# Layout title for CV

Tags: cv

It's my first time on LaTeX and writing my CV. I have some difficulties on layout of my docs. The following code is the problem:

```
\textbf{\underline{Design d'un avion pompier}}\\

\text{Analyse de compétiteurs}
\text{Définition du trajet de l'avion pompier}
\text{Établir une personnalisation de l'avion à l'aide de Catia V5}
\text{Modéliser les structures d'ailes d'avion (longerons)}
\text{Analyse aérodynamique à l'aide de calculs théoriques et d'un simulateur airflow}
\text{Méthode de calcul de performance de l'avion pour tous les phases de vol}
\text{Construction d'abaque pour optimisation de l'avion(Graphe Stress Analysis, Trim design, $C_{m}$ vs \alpha)}
\text{Suivi hebdomadaire avec l'équipe pour visualiser avancements/contraintes/questionnements sur le projet}
\\
\underline{\textbf{Identification des paramètres de découpe de matériaux recyclables}}\\
\text{Analyse des besoins du client}
\text{Établir un cahier des charges}
\text{Recueillir des informations sur les types de matières recyclables}
\text{Cherchez des fournisseurs locaux}
\text{Demandes d’échantillons}
\text{Effectuer des tests de découpes}
\text{Faire une analyse des résultats}
\\
\underline{\textbf{Conception d'un réservoir d'eau}}\\
\text{Conception d’une machine pour distribuer l’eau dans les festivals}
\text{Identifier le client et analyser ses besoins}
\text{Établir un cahier des charges}
\text{Modéliser le prototype sur le logiciel Catia V5}
\text{Faire des calculs de résistance des matériaux de système}
\text{Construction de notre prototype et le présenter devant nos collègues}
\text{Faire des suivis à chaque étape pour l’amélioration de la dynamique d’équipe}
```

First and second title (letter b) are centered and I want it to begin at the left. I tried with command begin{flushleft}, doesn't work. Someone have an idea to fix it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome. // Unfortunatley your code won't compile when we copy it. To improve your post, kindly follow this checklist: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason why almost every line is encapsulated in `\text`?

Comment: Anyway, your code doesn't compile because you're using `\alpha` outside of math mode. Please enclose that command in `$...$` or `\(...\)`. Also, some of your apostrophes are right single quotation marks `’` (U+2019) rather than standard "straight" apostrophes `'` (U+0027).